# Meteor - return asynchronous function to handlebar template?

Tags: asynchronous, meteor, handlebars.js

I am trying to generate a Flickr url based on a Flickr API call, and then return that result to a handlebars.js template. I am struggling to find a way around asynchronous processes.

I have tried to create a callback function, but I am still uncertain how to get a defined object or variable into the HTML template.

Here is the code for the Flickr API function:

```
var FlickrRandomPhotoFromSet = function(setID,callback){
Meteor.http.call("GET","http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key="+apiKey+"&photoset_id="+setID+"&format=json&nojsoncallback=1",function (error, result) {
    if (result.statusCode === 200) 
    var photoResult = JSON.parse(result.content);
    var photoCount = photoResult.photoset.total;
    var randomPhoto = Math.floor((Math.random()*photoCount)+1);
    var selectedPhoto = photoResult.photoset.photo[randomPhoto];
    var imageURL = "<img src=http://farm"+selectedPhoto.farm+".staticflickr.com/"+selectedPhoto.server+"/"+selectedPhoto.id+"_"+selectedPhoto.secret+"_b.jpg/>";
    FlickrObject.random = imageURL;
    }
    if (callback && typeof(callback)==="function") {
        callback();
    }
});};
```

My template code is this:

```
Template.backgroundImage.background = function(){
    FlickrRandomPhotoFromSet(setID,function(){
        return FlickrObject;
    });
};
```

But this still leaves me stuck, not able to get a defined object into my HTML, which is coded as such:

```
<template name="backgroundImage">
<div id="background">
    {{random}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `Session` as an intermediary. It is reactive so as soon as its set it will change the template with the new data:

```
Template.backgroundImage.background = function(){
    return Session.get("FlickrObject");
};

Template.backgroundImage.created = function() {
    FlickrRandomPhotoFromSet(setID,function(){
        Session.set("FlickrObject", FlickrObject)
    });
}
```

So the `created` method will be run when the template is created to run `FlickrRandomPhotoFromSet`, when the result is returned it will set the Session hash which in turn will set the background as soon as the result is received.

Be careful with your `FlickrRandomPhotoFromSet` too, I didn't notice you had an argument for `FlickrObject` to pass to the callback.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've decided to eliminate the Flickr object (which was purely an attempt to get the variable out of the function) and I've passed the url directly to the Session object from within the function. The Template.backgroundImage.background template script now returns the Session.get. Everything now works as intended except that the URL is returned in duplicate quotation marks and I haven't yet figured out how to eliminate that...!

Comment: You could use something like `/"([^"]+)"/i.exec(FlickrObject)[1]` instead of `FlickrObject` when you set the Session hash. I used `FlickrObject` but you can rename it to whatever you have, the expression is a regexp expression that gets rid of the encapsulating double quotes